# React Native Android - How can I generate the ripple effect on a TouchableHighlight?

Tags: react-native

So what I want to do is create a button that has a pressed state and unpressed state (hence why I'm using TouchableHighlight), i.e.

```
_onShowUnderlay = () => {
  this.setState({pressed: true})
}

_onHideUnderlay = () => {
  this.setState({pressed: false})
}

 <TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this.props.onPress}
  style={containerStyle} //style controlled by this.state.pressed
  onHideUnderlay={this._onHideUnderlay}
  onShowUnderlay={this._onShowUnderlay}>
  {this.props.image}
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

so usually I would use TouchableNativeFeedback to do this of course, but I can't do that here since I need to use the onHideUnderlay and onShowUnderlay of the TouchableHighlight to control the state.

So how can I achieve both the ripple and a pressed/unpressed state?

Comment: Have you tried the package? Did it help you?

Comment: I ended up animating it myself, thanks though.

Comment: Great! Have you done an npm package? that would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a npm package that does the job for you : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-button

Here is the implementation if you are interested : https://github.com/recr0ns/react-native-material-button/blob/master/index.js

**Looks like there is issues with the package itself.** I am currently looking for a better one.

This is a great package ideal. I would need it too.

Hope this helps